# Filter Payload with Dataweave for a Set Variable component

Tags: anypoint-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

For the Mulesoft 4.2 Set Variable component, I want to assign a simple String value pulled from a single specific record from an incoming JSON payload.

In my case, taking just the value from the 'country' field from below example:

```
[
  {
    "salesID": "4404Bob Builder210032011-02-18T15:52:21+0.00",
    "id": "4404",
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Builder",
    "address": "181 Construction Road, Adelaide, NSW",
    "postal": "21003",
    "country": "New Zealand",
    "creationDate": "2011-02-18T15:52:21+0.00",
    "accountType": "personal",
    "miles": 17469
  }
]
```

A non-dynamic way to do this is like:

```
payload[0].country
```

I believe the best way to do this is with the filter function.  The below option gives me the entire object, but I just want the country field.

```
payload filter ($.id == "4404")
```

Map function seems to be overkill for this since I only want the value, itself. I must be missing the syntax to get at the country field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some more investigating, and this solution got me close enough to what I wanted:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43488566/11995149

For my code example using filter, I had to surround the whole expression in parenthesis, and then I can access the field with a dot reference,
but below code gives String value as a single record within an array:

```
(payload filter ($.id == "4404")).country
```

```
[
  "New Zealand"
]
```

In my case, I know that just one result will be returned from the filtered payload, so I could get just the String value with:

```
(payload filter ($.id == "4404"))[0].country
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF2CS.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try any of below options:

1) (payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.id))["4404"][0].country
OR
2) (payload map ((item, index) -> if(item.id == "4404") item.country else ""))[0]

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: Thanks @Ashish.  Your option #2 was successful.  That's a nice skill for me to learn how you can use map or filter as a way to achieve the same result (at least in my simple case).  I think I would prefer a solution idea I found with filter because it is easier to read.
For solution #1, I am seeing a syntax error, but maybe the fix is simple. Not sure though:
"
Invalid input "groupBy ((item, index) -> item.id))", expected Namespace or Attribute<'@('(Name:Value)+')'> (line 1, column 9)
"